# убрать пробелы из строки средствами c#

Tags: c#

Как лучше написать код для удаления символов пробела из строки?

Comment: Чем вам `Replace` не нравится?

Comment: Мне нравится `Replace`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Этот код:

```
"      da ta    ".Replace(" ", "")
```

Вернет `"data"`

Еще пример:

```
var str = " some str ";
var strWithoutSpaces = str.Replace(" ", "");
Console.WriteLine(strWithoutSpaces); //somestr
```

Можно также добавить null-условный оператор:

```
string nullstr = null;
var nullstrWithoutSpaces = nullstr?.Replace(" ", "");
Console.WriteLine(nullstrWithoutSpaces); //null
```

Если необходимо убрать только пробелы из начала и конца строки, то можно воспользоваться методом Trim:

```
string str = "   da ta   ";
var trimmedstr = str.Trim();
Console.WriteLine(trimmedstr); //da ta
```

Comment: Да-да. И грохнется если строка будет null. Поправьте.

Comment: @AK добавил вариант с  оператором ?. .

Answer (score 4):

Используйте Replace:

```
string original = " some string ";
string replaced = original?.Replace(" ", "");
```

Вывод:

> `somestring`

Если на входе будет null, то вернёт null.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что вернуть `null` правильнее чем бросить исключение?

Comment: Кстати, да, исключение выглядит семантичнее.

Comment: @Андрей а с чего вы взяли, что бросить исключение правильнее, чем вернуть null для null?

Comment: Может лучше написать, что можно вернуть null, и что можно бросить исключение. И пускай каждый пишет так как считает нужным?

Comment: @Max любой вправе взять и запостить развернутый ответ с несколькими вариантами. И получить за это заслуженные плюсы. Спрашивать автора другого ответа "а с чего вы взяли что так правильнее" - это верный способ получить в ответ "а вот с того!". Ну или "?. выглядит семантичее!".

Comment: @PashaPash, я не считаю что тот или иной вариант единственно верный. Просто автор этого ответа упрекнул параллельный ответ в том, что он упадет. Но ведь в вопросе не указано какой результат должен быть если входная строка `null`. Вот я и спрашиваю автора с чего он взял что его вариант правильнее.

Comment: @Андрей не упрекнул, а просто подсказал про случай с null. не подсказал бы - там бы так и остался ответ-однострочник :)

Comment: Я просто попросил автора другого ответа расписать подробнее свой ответ. Через пару минут мне нужно было бежать с работы на тренировку и я рядом запостил свою версию (в комментах код некрасиво смотрится).